# The dollar ($) prefixed field '$divide' in "weight.$divide" is not valid for storage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got the following update query in NodeJS with the underlying `mongodb` driver used by mongoose, 3.5.5, using the latest MongoDB server, 4.2.5 Community:

```
    await mongoose.connection.db.collection('cluster1kms').updateOne({"location.coordinates": [point.longitude, point.latitude]}, {
                        $set: {
                            weight: {
                                $divide: [
                                    {
                                        $add: [
                                            {
                                                $multiply: ["$weight", "$count"]
                                            },
                                            point.weight
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        $add: ["$count", 1]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        $inc: {"count": 1}
                    }, {upsert: false});
```

As seen in the title, I keep getting the problem that `$divide` is not a valid storage name. MongoDB is supposed to allow aggregated pipelines in the updates, but I seem not to be having success with this. Tried the same also in the online MongoDB web shell, and the error is the same.

Am I missing anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as you said MongoDB allows [aggregated pipelines](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting in version 4.2 but the syntax to use them has changed a little.

In your case it's somewhat easy, we just need to wrap the update section with `[]` and change the `$inc` as pipelined updates do not support it.

```
await mongoose.connection.db.collection('cluster1kms').updateOne({"location.coordinates": [point.longitude, point.latitude]},
    [
        {
            $set: {
                weight: {
                    $divide: [
                        {
                            $add: [
                                {
                                    $multiply: ["$weight", "$count"]
                                },
                                point.weight
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            $add: ["$count", 1]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                count: {$add: ["$count", 1]} // this replaces the $inc.
            }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: Shit, have been on this all day, and thought that I had looked character for character, except for brackets. Thanks